# Diagonalizable by orthonormal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Explain why $A$ can be diagonalized by an orthonormal matrix and find an orthonormal matrix $Q$ and a diagonal $D$ such that $A = QDQ^T$.

**My approach** : Seems like a problem that goes around the eigenvalue-eigenmatrix thing. So, $x_A(λ)=\det(λI-A) = -(λ-4)(λ-1)^2$ is the characteristic polynomial. We get that the eigenvalues are : $λ_1 = 4$, $λ_2=λ_3=1$. It's easy to find the eigenvectors then, that are : $v_1 = (1,1,1)^T$, $v_2=(1,0,-1)^T$, $v_3=(-1,1,0)^T$. We can proceed after that to the standard diagonalization form, with the diagonal matrix formed by the eigenvalues and the orthonormal matrices formed by the eigenvectors.

Is my approach correct? **HOW** do I explain first of all why can $A$ be diagonalized by an orthonormal matrix ? After that, the question that follows is answered by my solution ? I'd really appreciate some help over this, it's an old exam question that I am looking over for my end-terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is completely correct, and you can justify it by remembering:

1) A symmetric matrix is *always* diagonalizable and all its eigenvalues are real;

2) For a symmetric matrix, eigenvectors belonging to *different* eigenvalues are **orthogonal**

The last property is exactly what allows you to orthogonally diagonalize your matrix: observe that eigenvectors belonging to the different eigenvalues of the matrix are *not only* linearly independent but in fact orthogonal. Now you only need to apply Gram-Schmidt within each eigenspace separatedly, and that's all.

Comment: Thanks, great answer ! Well, by applying Gram-Schmidt within each eigenspace separately you mean that you just do : $v_1 ' = \frac{v_1}{||v_1||}$  and so for the rest ones ?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos Exactly, you only need to normalize as orthogonality you already have it between eigenvectors belonging to different eigenvalues. In this case, you only need G-S for the two linearly independent eigenvectors belonging to $\;\lambda=1\;$, and then just normalize the eigenvector belonging to $\;\lambda=4\;$ ,as it already is orthogonal with the first two.

Comment: So just to make sure, I apply Gram-Schmidt to the two eigenvectors for $λ=1$ as follows : $v_2 ' = \frac{v_2}{||v_2||}$ and then the thing for $v_3 '$ with the inner product stuff. After that I just do $v_1 ' = \frac{v_1}{||v_1||}$ and I have my orthogonal matrix. Now how do I find the corresponding diagonal matrix to this one ? Or is it the same ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos The corresponding diagonal matrix you *already know it*: it's the one with the eigenvalues on the main diagonal!:$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&4\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Okay, so that remains unchanged. Thanks so much !!

Answer (score 2):

The reason $A$ can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix is simply that it is symmetric.

There is one small problem with your solution : if you want the matrix formed by the eigenvectors to be orthogonal, you need to take orthonormal vectors. You can apply the Gram-Schmidt process to make the eigenvectors orthonormal; notice that since $v_1$ is orthogonal to $v_2$ and $v_3$ (which is expected since they are associated to different eigenvalues), you will only need to change $v_3$ and divide the eigenvectors by their norms.

Comment: Not diagonal, orthonormal/orthogonal.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because I saw it before the edit and it was mistaken.

Comment: Changed it now after the correction.